# Cannot change the (remote) default branch (`origin/HEAD`)

Tags: git

I wanted to change the remote default branch (`origin/HEAD`) stored in my local repository.

I already changed the default branch `master` to another branch `new-default-branch` on github.  But the `origin/HEAD` didn't change.  I couldn't figure out why it wouldn't update.

So then I deleted `master` on both local and remote.

Now `git rev-parse HEAD` returns a commit that I can't see in any history.

What is happening?  How do I get `origin/HEAD` to point to `new-default-branch`?

Comment: Did you try this https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/changing-the-default-branch

Answer (score 3):

You can (and probably should have) run:

```
git remote set-head origin --auto
```

At this point, however, there may be a bit more to fix up: read on.

#### What's going on

The setting stored in `origin/HEAD` in *your* repository (your clone) is your Git's memory of the setting stored in `HEAD` in the GitHub clone.  This is a lot like any normal remote-tracking name.  Unfortunately, for whatever reason, the Git authors chose not to have `git fetch` *update* this setting.

The GitHub clone is a Git repository, like any repository.  This means that, like any repository, it has a `HEAD` setting.  This name, `HEAD`, contains the name of the current branch in the GitHub repository.  But the GitHub side repository is a so-called *bare clone*, with no actual working tree.  There is nothing checked out, so the idea of a "current branch" is a bit peculiar.  On the other hand, whenever you clone *any* repository—from GitHub or not—you run:

```
git clone [-b <branch>] <url>
```

The `-b` option you use here tell your Git which branch name to create in your new clone.  If you *don't* use a `-b` option, your Git asks the other Git, which is reading from the other Git repository—in this case, the GitHub clone—what branch name *they recommend*.  The current branch is the recommendation.  This holds even in a bare clone, like that on GitHub.  So the current branch over on GitHub is the one your `git clone` command will check out, if you don't specify anything in particular at `git clone` time.

In any case, at `git clone` time, your Git reads the recommendation from their Git, and creates `origin/HEAD` from this.  So that's where your initial `origin/HEAD` comes from.  Even if you use `-b`, your Git still reads out their recommendation and uses that to create your (local) `origin/HEAD` name.  But after that, your Git doesn't bother updating it.

There are several ways to *force* your Git to update it:

```
git remote set-head origin <name>
```

changes your local `origin/HEAD`.  **This does not reach out to `origin` at all.**  It just sets your local `origin/HEAD`.  Since Git normally doesn't change `origin/HEAD`, your manual change here persists after this.  Or:

```
git remote set-head origin --auto
```

causes your Git to call up their Git, as it did during `git clone` originally, and ask it what branch it recommends.  Whatever name they send back, your Git then sets your `origin/HEAD` as if you'd typed in that name.  So this *reads* their `HEAD` and updates your `origin/HEAD`.

Finally, you can use the low-level (or *plumbing* ) command `git symbolic-ref`.  You should use this only if you're writing a program to set `origin/HEAD`: Git's plumbing commands are commands meant to be run by other commands, rather than by humans.

> So then I deleted `master` on both local and remote.

Since the GitHub repository was using some other branch as its current branch, and you were presumably also on some other branch or perhaps in *detached HEAD* mode, that's allowed.  The effect is simply that the *name* is gone.  The commits over on GitHub that were reachable *by* that name may (or may not) eventually be "garbage collected", if there is no other way to find them, but there is no predicting when or whether this will eventually happen.

**The same is true in your own repository.**  The *name* `master` is gone.  The commits themselves remain for some time—precisely how long is not very predictable.  If you don't want or need them, you can let your own Git eventually remove them.  If you *do* want them, create a new branch or tag name to remember them, so that your Git knows that they have value and should not be garbage-collected.

> Now `git rev-parse HEAD` returns a commit that I can't see in any history.

This suggests that you are in *detached HEAD* mode, perhaps as a result of running:

```
git checkout origin/HEAD
```

earlier.  That would allow you to delete the name `master`, since you're on no branch at all (you cannot delete the branch name you're "on", but being on *no* branch enables you to delete *all* your branch names!).

As long as you remain in this detached-HEAD mode, at the commit that used to be found via your branch name `master`, that commit will still be found via the special name `HEAD`.  Once you `git checkout` or `git switch` to some existing branch, though, that protection for these commits goes away.  If there is no *other* protection for these commits, they become eligible for garbage collection.

(There's a standard, albeit adjustable, minimum delay of at least 14 and usually 30 days before any commit will be garbage-collected in your local repository.  So you typically have at least a month to change your mind here.  You will, however, have to know or find the hash ID(s) of the commit(s) you want rescued, so it's usually a good idea to recover this by creating a branch name as soon as you realize that this was a mistake, if it was a mistake.)

To create a branch name, find the hash ID of the commit, and run:

```
git branch <new-name> <hash-id>
```

Or, in your case, if you want to restore the name `master` to identify this particular commit that you currently are finding via `HEAD`:

```
git branch master HEAD
```

will do the trick.

If you *don't* want this commit (and other commits reachable only from this one), you don't need to restore the name.

#### `origin/HEAD` is mostly useless

What's not clear to me is *why* you want to fix up your `origin/HEAD`.  It's not very useful.  It has a few small purposes:

- You can look at it to see what it's set to.  How valuable this is is up to you, but I've never actually *cared*.
- Running `git rev-parse origin` or other similar operations will, via the six-step procedure outlined in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), find `origin/HEAD` and resolve that to a hash ID.  Again, I've never actually *cared* about this.  It's there if you want to use it, e.g., `git rebase origin` instead of `git rebase origin/somebranch`.

(I'd personally be happier if `origin/HEAD` didn't exist and step 6 in the six steps in the link didn't exist.)

Answer (score 1):

I think either you can do it in Settings in GitHub to change the default branch, as mentioned by *@Georgios Syngouroglou*

or you can run below command in command line to change `origin/HEAD` to point to any other branch

```
git remote set-head origin new-default-branch
```

Regarding your question on how `git rev-parse HEAD` points to a commit which you can't figure out after deleting the branch,

Branches are just pointers to a commit, so even if you delete a branch, it won't delete your local commit, and the commits will be something like a dangling commit without any reference. `HEAD` might be still referencing the `HEAD` commit of `master` which you deleted and you can see that commit if you do `git reflog` or `git reflog show HEAD`

Run `git gc` to do the garbage cleaning and you can check again if HEAD points to a commit you can't see in History.